# How do I invoke a function value that serves as a parameter on a function?

Tags: f#

**How do I invoke a function value that serves as a parameter on a function?**

Specifically, my goal is to leverage a parameter of a function in which the parameter is actually a function.

In my case, I am trying to implement an interface for logging data.

**Here's my code:**

```
let logToFile (filePath:string) (message:string) =
    let file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
    file.WriteLine(message)
    file.Close()

let makeInitialDeposit deposit =
    let balance = deposit |> insert []
    sprintf "Deposited: %f" balance

let logDeposit deposit (log:'medium ->'data -> unit) =
    deposit |> makeInitialDeposit 
            |> log
```

**Note the following function:**

```
let logDeposit deposit (log:'medium ->'data -> unit) =
    deposit |> makeInitialDeposit 
            |> log
```

I get a compile error on the log function:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the
>   type annotations. The type variable 'medium has been constrained to be
>   type 'string'.

I understand that makeInitialDeposit returns string.
However, that string type is mapped to the generic type 'data.
Hence, a generic can be of any type right?

**I then tried supplying the medium (i.e. file) argument:**

```
let logDeposit deposit (log:'medium ->'data -> unit) medium =
    deposit |> makeInitialDeposit 
            |> log medium
```

**Then my error got updated to:**

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the
>   type annotations. The type variable 'data has been constrained to be
>   type 'string'.

**My Goal**

Ultimately, I just want to have an interface called log and pass in an implementation of that interface (i.e. logToFile).

Any guidance on how I should interpret the compile error based on my initial interpretation?

**Insert function dependencies**

```
let getBalance coins =
    coins |> List.fold (fun acc d -> match d with
                                     | Nickel         -> acc + 0.05
                                     | Dime           -> acc + 0.10
                                     | Quarter        -> acc + 0.25
                                     | OneDollarBill  -> acc + 1.00
                                     | FiveDollarBill -> acc + 5.00) 0.00

let insert balance coin =
    coin::balance |> getBalance
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the implementation for insert and removed semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have defined `log :'medium ->'data -> unit`.

You then take the result of `deposit |> makeInitialDeposit`, which has type `string` and pipe it into the `log` function.  The compiler, logically, then infers that `'medium = string`.

If you accept a `'medium` argument in your `logDeposit` function then you simply move that inference along a step, `deposit |> makeInitialDeposit` is still a `string` so now `'data = string`.

---

I think you are struggling though because these functions don't well model your domain and your logging logic is bleeding out into the rest of your code.

Why does `makeInitialDeposit` return a `string`?

Why does `getBalance` return a `float` but `insert` accepts a `Coin list` as its `balance` argument?

I would start by making a logging function that accepts three arguments:

```
let logToFile (filePath:string) (formatf : 'data -> string) data =
    use file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
    file.WriteLine(formatf data)
    data
```

It has type `filePath : string -> (formatf : 'data -> string) -> (data : 'data) -> data`.  It accepts a path to log to, a function that formats something of type `'data` as a string and some `'data` to log to the file.  Finally, it returns the `data` argument you supplied unchanged.  That means you can, in principle, insert logging of any arbitrary value in your code anywhere.

I then set up some functions in the domain like this:

```
let valueOf = function
    | Nickel         -> 0.05m
    | Dime           -> 0.10m
    | Quarter        -> 0.25m
    | OneDollarBill  -> 1.00m
    | FiveDollarBill -> 5.00m

let totalValue coins =
    coins |> List.fold (fun acc coin -> acc + valueOf coin) 0.0m

let insert coins coin = coin::coins // returns Coin list

let makeInitialDeposit deposit = insert [] deposit // returns Coin list
```

I can then use these functions, inserting logging at any arbitrary point:

```
let balance =
    makeInitialDeposit OneDollarBill
    |> logToFile "file.txt" (sprintf "Initial Deposit: %A")
    |> totalValue
    |> logToFile "file2.txt" (sprintf "Balance : $%M")
```

This approach lets you fit logging around your domain rather than building your domain around logging.

Comment: Thanks TheInnerLight. You answered the gist of my questions. Ultimately, I was/am struggling to figure out how to replace logTofile with a high-order function called log and then have logToFile invoked from the log function value.

Comment: @ScottNimrod You just need that extra `formatf` function to convert `'data` into a `string` for logging.  I'd recommend also creating logging for predefined types via partial application, you could supply the `'data -> string` conversion function for some commonly used types, then you can re-use them whenever you want to log the same data type.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a blog I can subscribe to? I really appreciate your  expertise on this language.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I don't at the moment but I have some things I plan to write about so it probably won't be long :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, it seems odd that you're passing in a string like `"Deposited: 0.25"` as your path name. What you probably wanted is to have `message` as your first parameter and `filePath` as your second parameter for `logToFile`. And accordingly for `log` to be `'data -> 'medium -> unit`.

Getting that out of the way, the issue for your compiler error is that `makeInitialDeposit` returns a string and when you then pipe that result into `log` the constraint happens. One way to get it to work is to add another parameter to `logDeposit` to converts string to `'data` like this:

```
let logDeposit deposit (log: 'data ->'medium-> unit) (stringConverter: string -> 'data) =
    deposit |> makeInitialDeposit
            |> stringConverter
            |> log
```

With this something like `let dummyLog (a:int) (b:string) = ()` will work assuming you pass in the appropriate converter from string to int.

Comment: Is there an alternative approach? Why isn't string a legal type? Why does this generic function all of a sudden care about a string type?

Comment: So using the minimal example you provided, string is a legal type. In fact, string constrains the type of `'data`. If that's not happening to you, something else is happening.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is, why do I need a string converter for a generic input value? In addition, I would like the community to vote up this answer before I select it as the answer. So far, I just upvoted your answer.

Comment: Because the compiler is inferring that the generic is always a string. This is because makeInitialDeposit can only return a string....